# How to take backup of Mysql databases in XAMPP without using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, xampp

**Here is my problem:**

Because of some issues `mysql` not working in `XAMPP 3.2.2` in windows 7. Then `phpmyadmin` in localhost shows *Access Denied*. So I want to reinstall the XAMPP. But, I'm unable to take backup of databases through phpmyadmin. Now how can I get the backup of databases. If I have the backup of data folder in `xampp -> mysql` then I'll copy the folder in new xampp folder then I'll get all my old databases with content or not. Is there any other way to get the backup of database?

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: Look into command line use of `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Yes, you will be able to recover.

1. Copy content from your `/installation_path/xampp/mysql` directory to your desired location.
2. ReInstall and copy back the content.
3. Restart your services.

[or]

If you have your backup in a Folder, do the following:

```
datadir = "your/path/mysql/backupdata"
```

in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini